# insert inside $_SESSION a string

Tags: php, session

I have a problem where I haven't found a solution to on the Internet.

My peace of code is:

```
$username = $_POST["nkn"];
$_SESSION['user'] = $username;
```

Then, when I use:

```
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

nothing appears.

Can be the problem on the second line of the first piece of code?

If yes, I haven't found a PHP method such as `strcpy` or similar. How can I do a string copy?

Comment: do you have `session_start();` at the top, to start with?

Comment: `session_start();` is needed to be on top of every page using sessions. A common overlook.

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}`

Comment: @user2510406 You're welcome. Have my comments solved your problem then?

Comment: Answer can be found at the bottom of tag info http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Comment: No need to write `[solved]` in the title. Instead, to mark the question as resolved, please just mark an answer as selected - nothing more is needed.

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn't mark it as `[solved]`, just in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

`session_start();` may not be present at the top of the affected pages using sessions.

**Solution:**

`session_start();` is needed to be placed on top of every page using sessions, usually immediately follow the PHP opening tag `<?php`.

**Example:**

```
<?php

session_start();

// rest of code

?>
```

More on the subject can be found by visiting the PHP.net Website.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php